# Covert a long string to number

Tags: reactjs

Want to convert a string to a number. I tried Number(), parseInt() but the result is like,
if the string  is "586486785469547948790470945870879003409" the result is => 5.8648678546954796e+38
How to covert is as a number without using mathematical notations

Answer (score 2):

use the built in `BigInt` type:

```
const hugeBin = BigInt("586486785469547948790470945870879003409");
```

see also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt

`BigInt` is supported in all modern browsers, such as Chrome 67+, Edge 79+, Firefox 68+, Safari 14+ (see link above for more).

Support in NodeJS was added in version 10.4.0.

Comment: I got an error while using BigInt. 'BigInt' is not defined  no-undef

Comment: @Leya Varghese maybe this link will help you https://www.npmjs.com/package/big-integer

Comment: @LeyaVarghese what browser are you targeting (and using for testing)? Most modern browsers should support `BigInt`, as does nodejs 10+. Is this error only shown in your linter? Then you may need to configure ESLint (or whatever you're using), e.g. https://futurestud.io/tutorials/eslint-how-to-fix-bigint-is-not-defined

Answer (score 0):

using built-in (BigInt or Number)

```
const bigNum= BigInt(//number)
const bigNum= Number(//number)
```